# Mathematical symbol for Symbolic Replacement

Tags: terminology, mathematica

> (Posted at [mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84441/mathematical-symbol-and-name-for-symbolic-replacement), as it might be better there)

I'm searching for a mathematical symbol, that describes the symbolic replacement done for instance in Mathematica:

`f[xx_, a_, b_] := 3*xx /. {a -> b}
(* f[3*a*b, a, d]  gives 9 b d *)`

or

`g[exp_] := exp /. {a_[n_] -> a[-n + 2]}
(* g[3 b[3 + m]^2] gives 3 b[-1 - m]^2 *)`

Is there a mathematical symbol and term to describe such transformations (which is denoted as `/.` + a substituation list with `{ someA -> someB }` in Mathematica)?

PS: I see that there are two things I use here. First, the mathematica-functions `f[xx_, a_, b_]` and `g[exp_]` seem to be [functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28mathematics%29) (their arguments are functions). And then, there are those symbolic replacement operations denoted by `/. { someA -> someB}`. I am interested in the mathematically correct name for the second part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean assigning a new value to some variable? In that case, $:=$ is often used, especially in computer science. The symbol $\leftarrow$ is also often used, and is perhaps more intuitively understandable, as the value on the right-hand side is "put into" the variable on the left-hand side.

Closely related, := is also sometimes used as the symbol for defining a variable, so that
$$a := 5x$$
means that $a$ is equal to $5x$ *by definition*. Other notations for this include $\stackrel{def}{=}$, $\stackrel{\Delta}{=}$, and $\equiv$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that I didn't explain well enough what I meant. I wanted to know a name for the `/.` used in mathematica. (i changed the question to make that clearer). Do you know some symbol for that?

Comment: @NicoDean I'm afraid not, I'm not very familiar with Mathematica. It kind of looks like an anonymous function to me, but I really don't know.